# Yii filtering related models' attributes: is there a limitation on number of static model queries in a view?

Tags: gridview, model, static, yii, limit

I have a small issue. In admin.php bootstrap grid, I'm [filtering to related model attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/42096-filtering-related-model-attribute-in-grid-with-together/page__p__200183__fromsearch__1#entry200183). With basic textfield filtering situation it's working, but we have to select as a dropdown. so I have put this into the grid columns:

```
'filter' => GxHtml::listDataEx(Order::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true,
array('order' => 'CAST(ordernr AS SIGNED)')), 'ordernr', 'ordernr'),
```

it works very good at the first 6 columns, but after that, the dropdowns are empty
how can it be? it should work. every line is basically the same. is there a limitation, how many static model queries are allowed in a view in Yii?

thanks.
BR
c

Comment: for now the problem seems to be solved, please check the link, it's not a real solution, but the problem is not a problem for now. it seem it was too much for Yii, and now I have optimized a bit in the code and Yii now has to work a little bit less, so now it's okay, but if we want to use more columns, can be a problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now the problem seems to be solved, please check [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/42096-filtering-related-model-attribute-in-grid-with-together/page__view__findpost__p__211549), it's not a real solution, but the problem is not a problem for now. it seem it was too much for Yii, and now I have optimized a bit in the code and Yii now has to work a little bit less, so now it's okay, but if we want to use more columns, can be a problem again.